# Can't get my head around the "name" value in putting and getting data from intents for use between activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two activities that I'm trying to share a value between using an Intent extra. From what I can tell through debugging, the value is correctly placed in the intent, and when `onResult()` is called in the originating activity the value seems to remain intact. However my TextView displays Textnull instead of the text entered in the text edit in the second activity.

Something I don't understand with the Intent extras is what the "name" value does and what it's meant to point to, and I imagine this is the heart of the problem (though I'm just as likely wrong).

I'll copy the code from my two activities and if you guys can tell me how to use the name value correctly, or if I've totally misidentified the problem, that'd be amazing.

[The initial activity that launches the second and waits for a result back.](http://pastebin.com/9RZXYK7S)

[The second activity in which text is entered and result returned with the data packaged in the intent.](http://pastebin.com/Fc0CrwC0)

Comment: Could you post your code? Also, briefly state what you expect and what is happening. Your question is a bit wordy. :)

Comment: I haven't had time to test this, but my hunch is that you are calling `EditText.getText()` - this returns an `Editable` instance. You may want to call `EditText.getText().toString()` instead.

Comment: Try `resultIntent.putExtra("text", mEditText.getText().toString());` because `mEditText.getText()` does not return `String`. It returns `Editable` which can't be accessed via `data.getStringExtra("text")`.

Comment: Damn. Cheers. Just shows how much tunnel vision can blind you. That's resolved the issue, thanks.

Comment: In effect, you name your Intent Extras just like you name your variables or database fields: to uniquely identify them.  You could very well write a program which expected multiple extras of the same (String) type each having a different purpose, and so needing to be kept distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@npace is right.

In your `enterClicked()`, you need to write:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("text", mEditText.getText().toString());
```

`getText()` returns your an instance of `Editable`, but you actually need a string.

Comment: That resolved the issue perfectly. I had a feeling I'd developed tunnel vision here, but I couldn't pull myself out of it for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: @KennethWyatt if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.